# simple toastr notification messages

Tags: javascript, css, notifications

I want to implement simple toastr(notification) functionality without toastr plugin.

I want to remove transitioned class of the last added element after 5s.

```
var loadNotification = function(typeClass, message) {
    var notification = {
        typeClass: typeClass || 'alert-success',
        message: message
    };

    var template = UTILS.getHandleBarTemplate('#template-notification');
    var templateMarkup = template(notification);
    $('.notifications-area').append(templateMarkup);


    $('.notifications-area').find('.q-notifications').last().addClass('transitioned');
};
```

Current Implementaion:

[Notifications Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibBq1.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimout()` and `removeClass` to remove class you want. When you add the transitioned class at the same time call setTimeout with 5000(5sec)

```
var loadNotification = function(typeClass, message) {
    var notification = {
        typeClass: typeClass || 'alert-success',
        message: message
    };

    var template = UTILS.getHandleBarTemplate('#template-notification');
    var templateMarkup = template(notification);
    $('.notifications-area').append(templateMarkup);


    $('.notifications-area').find('.q-notifications').last().addClass('transitioned');
   setTimout(function(){
   $('.notifications-area').find('.q-notifications').last().removeClass('transitioned');
   },5000);
};
```

Comment: removing the last element was not predictable as there can be new notification added and it will always remove the class of the last element added which is wrong. so I added an ID for each notification. and removed that element after a certain interval.

Answered my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44496961/6774615

Comment: @TabraizAli any way i was assumed that you need setTimeout funtion

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh for answering this. helped me arrive at a solution

Answer (score 0):

removing the last element was not predictable as there can be new notification added and it will always remove the class of the last element added which is wrong. so I added an ID for each notification. and removed that element after certain interval.

```
var notificationId = $('.notifications-area').find('.q-notifications').length;
    var notification = {
        typeClass: typeClass || 'alert-failure',
        message: message,
        notificationId: notificationId
    };

    var template = QUBOLE.UTILS.getHandleBarTemplate('#template-notification');
    var templateMarkup = template(notification);
    $('.notifications-area').append(templateMarkup);

    // Adding transitioned class quickly doesn't have apply the css transition
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#notification_'+notificationId).addClass('transitioned');
    }, 0);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#notification_'+notificationId).removeClass('transitioned');
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#notification_'+notificationId).remove();
    }, 6000);
```